# Linux expect expecting a hyphen in the prompt

Tags: linux, expect

So, I have an expect script that goes out to an HPE virtual connect module to run a show all command. However, when I am "Expecting" the prompt "->", Im getting an error:

```
bad flag "-> ": must be -glob, -regexp, -exact, -notransfer, -nocase, -i, -indices, -iread, -timestamp, -timeout, -nobrace, or --
while executing
 "expect "-> ""
(file "./expect_vc_showall.ziUzpF" line 10)
```

Here is my code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect -f
 set timeout 60
 set ip_hostname [lindex $argv 0];
 #log_user 0
 spawn ssh Administrator@$ip_hostname
 expect {
     "*yes/no*" { send "yes\r"; exp_continue }
     "*assword:" { send "password123\r" }
  }
 expect "-> "
 send "show all\r"
 #log_user 1
 expect "-> "
 send "exit\r"
```

I have tried to use expect -- "-> " but that just brings me to the prompt and then dies.

Here is what the prompt looks like:

```
 Last login: Thu Jul 27 17:09:28 2017 from 172.16.100.78
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 HP Virtual Connect Management CLI v4.41
 Build: 4.41-6 (r315367) Mar  5 2015 13:59:31
 (C) Copyright 2006-2015 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, L.P.
 All Rights Reserved
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 GETTING STARTED: 

 help           : Displays a list of available subcommands 
 exit           : Quits the command shell 
 <subcommand> ? : Displays a list of managed elements for a subcommand 
 <subcommand> <managed element> ? : Displays detailed help for a command 

 ->
```

If I just do a expect "> ", it dies at the first subcommand text.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Thanks!
Joe

Comment: What about escaping it like `\->`?

Comment: Tried that too and it just brings me to the prompt. Doesnt send the show all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default pattern type for expect is a glob, and there is an explicit flag for that:

```
expect -gl "-> "
```

However, your pattern has no glob characters, so you could also use the exact flag:

```
expect -ex "-> "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
expect -- "-> "
```

or use a glob pattern that doesn't start with a hyphen (much messier)

```
expect {[-]> }
```

Comment: Hi There. Thanks! I will have to try this when I get back to work on Mon. I did try expect -- "-> " but that just brought me inside to the -> prompt waiting for a command... It didnt send the show all command in the next line. 

I will try the glob pattern though and see how that work.

Thanks!

Comment: while developing an expect script, `expect -d script.exp` is very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the info Glenn!